# Laravel: Trying to compare only the simple date, not hours minutes and seconds

Tags: php, date, datetime, laravel, laravel-4

```
$datetime = new DateTime('today');
$datetime->modify('+2 day');

$expired_tags = DB::table('tags')
        ->where('active', '=', 1)
        ->where('expiry_date', '=', $datetime)
        ->get();
```

I'm trying to understand how I can ask:

Give me all tags that are two days away from being expired. But the above seems to be taking the Hour, Minute and Second into account ... I simply need to ask for the Year, Month, Day and compare that aspect of the two dates.

Comment: Never used laravel, but will laravel's DB layer handle DateTime objects like that: `->where('expiry_date', '=', $datetime)` ? Or should you use `->format()` on DateTime object before sending it to `->where()` method?

Comment: just a note: Laravel uses the Carbon library for dates, so you can learn far more by learning about that: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so I figured out a great way of doing what I want ...

```
$starting_time = new DateTime('today');
$starting_time->modify('+1 day');

$ending_time = new DateTime('today');
$ending_time->modify('+1 day +23 hours +59 minutes +59 seconds');

$expired_tags = DB::table('tags')
        ->where('active', '=', 1)
        ->whereBetween('expiry_date', array($starting_time, $ending_time))
        ->get();
```

This grabs all records that have a `datetime` anytime during the next calendar day! :)

Comment: Or `$ending_time->modify('+2 day -1 second');`

Comment: OH! That's even better! Thanks a lot for that, @Glavić

Comment: +1, you did it by yourself, didn't just ask but you tried hard.

Answer (score 2):

```
$today = new DateTime('today');

$expired_tags = DB::table('tags')
        ->where('active', '=', 1)
        ->where('expiry_date', '>=', $today->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('expiry_date', '<',  $today->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->get();
```